# Web view with No suitable EGL configs found error

Tags: android, webview

I'm new to android and I'm now trying to implement a `WebView` example. In my application, the `WebView` redirect to a web page. But below in Logcat this is the error it shows. I tried to solve it, but I can't. Help me find it please. I'm really sorry if my question bothers you . 
This is the error :

```
01-02 22:46:42.764: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
01-02 22:46:42.764: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
01-02 22:46:42.784: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
01-02 22:46:42.784: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
01-02 22:46:42.784: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)]  gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed


01-02 22:46:42.764: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs    found.
01-02 22:46:42.764: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
01-02 22:46:42.784: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
01-02 22:46:42.784: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
01-02 22:46:42.784: E/chromium(1223): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
01-02 22:46:44.724: W/AwContents(1223): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
01-02 22:46:45.694: W/AwContents(1223): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
01-02 22:46:45.954: W/AwContents(1223): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
```

This is the code I used :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.sportsone.jp/futsal/m/");
```

Comment: <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" /> add this to your manifest file and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately , Not working :(

Comment: Are you trying it on device or `AVD` ??

Comment: I ran the code in AVD

Comment: What version of AVD you are using??

Comment: Have you enable the Emulator GPU ?

Comment: No not yet . Is it needed ?

Comment: Just enable it and check if it works ...

Comment: 01-03 00:05:40.361: E/eglCodecCommon(1133): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
01-03 00:05:40.381: E/eglCodecCommon(1133): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
01-03 00:05:41.521: E/eglCodecCommon(1133): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
01-03 00:05:41.521: E/eglCodecCommon(1133): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
01-03 00:05:41.571: E/eglCodecCommon(1133): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44

Comment: The site which you are displaying may be that uses OpenGL so just check by enabling the GPU on your Avd tell me if that worked for you.

Comment: above are new error :(

Comment: Why not use an actual device for testing?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes EGL errors can be resolved by simply restarting the android virtual device.
Otherwise try enabling the emulator GPU.
To do this in Eclipse go to Window > AVD MANAGER select your AVD and click "Edit...".
Check the "Use Host GPU" box, then save and restart your AVD.

Comment: Error gone and I think it also increase performance of virtual machine